# Does a MongoDB shard key index double as a normal index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

I have a MongoDB collection that was indexed on userId - the index is "userId_1". At some point, we decided to shard the collection, and the shard key was chosen as the userId. As a result, another index was created on the collection - the index is "userId_hashed".

As a result, I've now got two indexes on this fairly large collection (about 100GB at the moment), and I'm concerned it may be wasteful to be maintaining both of these indexes on the collection. They seem like they could be redundant with one another.

I know I need to keep the "userId_hashed" index for sharding, and I know that a hashed index has the constraint that you can only filter with equality checks, and not ranges. Given that "userId" identifies a unique user in the system, querying for userId in a range doesn't make sense, or at least, isn't an operation we need to support.

So, can I just delete the "userId_1" index? Will queries on that field effectively use the "userId_hashed" index correctly and efficiently? Here's an example of the type of query we most often run against this collection:

```
db.history.find({ "userId": "abc123" }).sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(10)
```

Or for paging:

```
db.history.find({ "userId": "abc123", "_id": { $lt: ObjectId("blah1") }}).sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(10)
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#sharding-shard-key-indexes), the existing `userId_1` index should have prevented the need to create another index on `userId` just for sharding.

Comment: Hmm, based on what I have implemented on my end...that appears to not be the case. Not sure how I got to that scenario!

Comment: What were the actual commands you issued to set up the sharding? Noting the name is `_hashed` here. [Hashed indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/#create-a-hashed-index) are **different** to standard indexes. So it looks like you actually asked for it.

Comment: Your query examples have equality matches on `userId` but also sort and  `$lt` comparison using  `_id`. For efficient querying (and avoiding the [32MB limit for in-memory sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations)) you would ideally want a compound index on `{userId:1, _id: -1}`. See:  [Use indexes to sort query results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/). Before dropping any indexes I'd suggest [measuring index usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/).